# How do I write my jQuery to let me swap each images as many times as I want?

Tags: jquery, image, swap

I'm writing jQuery code to solve a puzzle. A 3x3 table has an image in each cell (8 picture images and 1 white square image) but they can only switch if the clicked image is adjacent to a white/blank square. My code is working to the point that it will only allow adjacent images to move. However, I can only swap each image once. How do I write it to let me swap each images as many times as I want?

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    $("img").click(function(){
        var blankSquare = $("#blank");
        var blankIndex = $("img").index(blankSquare);
        //alert(blankIndex); //this updates as square moves
        var imageSquare = $(this);  
        var imageIndex = $("img").index(this); //returns index of selected image 
        //alert(imageIndex); //will update as selected image changes
        //swap image if it's index (position) is next adjacent to the white square      
        if(imageSquare !== blankSquare) {
            if(imageIndex == 0 && blankIndex == 1) { //switch if image is at index 0
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 0 && blankIndex == 3) { //switch if image is at index 0
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 1 && blankIndex == 0) { //switch if image is at index 1
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 1 && blankIndex == 2) { //switch if image is at index 1
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 1 && blankIndex == 4) { //switch if image is at index 1
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
                imageClicked.data('clicked') == false;
            } else if(imageIndex == 2 && blankIndex == 1) { //switch if image is at index 2
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 2 && blankIndex == 5) { //switch if image is at index 2
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 3 && blankIndex == 0) { //switch if image is at index 3
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 3 && blankIndex == 4) { //switch if image is at index 3
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 3 && blankIndex == 6) { //switch if image is at index 3
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 4 && blankIndex == 1) { //switch if image is at index 4
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 4 && blankIndex == 3) { //switch if image is at index 4
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 4 && blankIndex == 5) { //switch if image is at index 4
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 4 && blankIndex == 7) { //switch if image is at index 4
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 5 && blankIndex == 2) { //switch if image is at index 5
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 5 && blankIndex == 4) { //switch if image is at index 5
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 5 && blankIndex == 8) { //switch if image is at index 5
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 6 && blankIndex == 3) { //switch if image is at index 6
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 6 && blankIndex == 7) { //switch if image is at index 6
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 7 && blankIndex == 4) { //switch if image is at index 7
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 7 && blankIndex == 6) { //switch if image is at index 7
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 7 && blankIndex == 8) { //switch if image is at index 7
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 8 && blankIndex == 5) { //switch if image is at index 8
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            } else if(imageIndex == 8 && blankIndex == 7) { //switch if image is at index 8
                imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
                imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
            }
        }//end of !== if-statement
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tile Game</title>
    <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="puzzle2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
<tr>
  <td><img src="SockeyOneRow3A.jpg" /></td>
  <td><img src="SockeyOneRow2B.jpg" /></td>
  <td><img src="SockeyOneRow3B.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><img src="SockeyOneRow2A.jpg" /></td>
  <td><img id="blank" src="blank.jpg"  /></td>
  <td><img src="SockeyOneRow1B.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><img src="SockeyOneRow1A.jpg" /></td>
  <td><img src="SockeyOneRow2C.jpg" /></td>
  <td><img src="SockeyOneRow3C.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML as well, and if possible a Fiddle would be great!

Comment: I added the HTML. I'm not sure what Fiddle is, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I should answer my own post or not, but I figured it out.

I switched to using the attr() method. So first I found the sources of my blank image and my clicked image and stored them into separate variables.

```
var blankSource = $(blankSquare).attr("src");
var imageSource = $(imageSquare).attr("src");
```

I then switched the source of the selected image with that of the blank image. The blank image variable (blankSquare) was created with it's ID so I had to transfer that with the blank image as well. Here's that code:

```
imageSquare.attr("src", blankSource); //this sets the blank image's source to the clicked image's source
imageSquare.attr("id", "blank"); //this sets an the ID value of "blank" the clicked image
blankSquare.attr("src", imageSource); //this sets the clicked image's source to the blank image's source
blankSquare.attr("id", " "); //this removes the id from the blank image
```

This block of code replaced my original statements that appeared between my if-else statements. (There's probably a better way to set the adjacent restrictions, but this works.)

So this

```
imageSquare.replaceWith(blankSquare);
imageSquare.detach().appendTo("td:empty");
```

became this

```
imageSquare.attr("src", blankSource);
imageSquare.attr("id", "blank");
blankSquare.attr("src", imageSource);
blankSquare.attr("id", " ");
```